# Possible bug NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_COUNTRY

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I am trying to enable policy via Android Management API.

```
{
      "name": "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/policies/default",
      "version": "2",
      "applications": [
        {
          "packageName": "app.caredirect.caredirecthub2",
          "installType": "KIOSK"
        },
        {
          "packageName": "com.android.settings",
          "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
          "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
        },
        {
          "packageName": "com.amazon.dee.app",
          "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
          "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
        }
      ],
      "systemUpdate": {
        "type": "WINDOWED",
        "startMinutes": 10,
        "endMinutes": 1439
      },
      "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true
    }
```

The store listing says for app.caredirect.caredirecthub2 that it is available in EVERY country.
Despite this I get the following error:

```
    {
  "name": "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/33ddb8137f60b585",
  "managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER",
  "state": "ACTIVE",
  "appliedState": "ACTIVE",
  "nonComplianceDetails": [{
    "settingName": "applications",
    "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
    "packageName": "app.caredirect.caredirecthub2",
    "installationFailureReason": "NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_COUNTRY"
  }, {
    "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities",
    "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
    "packageName": "app.caredirect.caredirecthub2"
  }],
  "enrollmentTime": "2020-09-23T15:02:52.290Z",
  "lastStatusReportTime": "2020-09-23T15:02:57.915Z",
  "lastPolicySyncTime": "2020-09-23T15:02:53.754Z",
  "appliedPolicyVersion": "1",
  "apiLevel": 28,
  "softwareInfo": {
    "androidVersion": "9",
    "androidDevicePolicyVersionCode": 1317100,
    "androidDevicePolicyVersionName": "13.17.10.v32",
    "androidBuildNumber": "TB-X605F_S210208_200807_ROW",
    "deviceKernelVersion": "3.18.120-perf-g1d02637-dirty",
    "bootloaderVersion": "unknown",
    "androidBuildTime": "2020-08-07T10:08:52Z",
    "securityPatchLevel": "2020-08-01",
    "primaryLanguageCode": "en-US",
    "deviceBuildSignature": "1c41fedecacbe89b81c242ecf74929f7d57322b64f8179c1c78a390a3494f14a",
    "systemUpdateInfo": {
      "updateStatus": "UP_TO_DATE"
    }
  },
  "hardwareInfo": {
    "brand": "Lenovo",
    "hardware": "qcom",
    "manufacturer": "LENOVO",
    "serialNumber": "HA0Y8JQX",
    "model": "Lenovo TB-X605F"
  },
  "appliedPolicyName": "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/policies/default",
  "memoryInfo": {
    "totalRam": "1909563392",
    "totalInternalStorage": "3121049600"
  },
  "userName": "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/users/106404730049843005283",
  "enrollmentTokenName": "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/enrollmentTokens/1019LI5YbxD4MNgIOfRKRxxKtK4ZLzRBZTGlL0Tw5Ns",
  "previousDeviceNames": ["enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/3832aa78af19d796", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/326e9eaec5f835db", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/3f22065004da99b8", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/3027d6b05179f8ac", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/3011e18ade8e09f3", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/36ea1951ef4e088f", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/30fb71bc476a4d1d", "enterprises/LC03hx99sc/devices/3695657a941cba4a"],
  "securityPosture": {
    "devicePosture": "SECURE"
  },
  "ownership": "COMPANY_OWNED"
}
```

What is causing NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_COUNTRY ?
This is preventing the whole kiosk setup from working.
thanks

Comment: I am also getting the error 'NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_COUNTRY' with a policy that is trying to install a kiosk app that is limited to a single country. Have you found a possible solution for this?

Comment: @JohanFerreira can't quite remember tbh. It worked after a while and I wasn't sure why. I think I resaved the google play app page country settings, recreated the kiosk policy and magically it worked. I felt it was a bug on google's end

Comment: Ok great thanks for the advice! Just another question, is your app's country settings also limited to a single country?